# Convert a WPF Swipe Transition Datatemplate with DataTriggers to Silverlight4

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, transition, datatrigger

I've got the following datatemplate in a WPF app I'm working on. This provides an awesome swipe transition and was originally taken from [this blog post](http://www.11011.net/wpf-transitions).

What I'd like to do is get the same thing working in Silverlight 4. To my horror, SL4 is missing DataTriggers and certain storyboards. Can anyone shed light on the equivalents? Alternatively, can you point to a swipe transition on the web in Silverlight I can poach? Thanks!!

**The Swipe Transition**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SwipeTransition">
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Visibility x:Key="Visible">Visible</Visibility>
            <Storyboard x:Key="SlideStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="container" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                    From="0" FillBehavior="Stop"
                    Duration="0:0:0.3"
                    DecelerationRatio="1.0"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="a" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.3" FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="b"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" 
                    Duration="0:0:0.3" FillBehavior="Stop">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource Visible}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <Common:Transition x:Name="transition" Source="{Binding}" />
            <Grid Name="container">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource NegativeConverter}}" />
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <ContentControl Name="a" Visibility="Hidden" Content="{Binding ElementName=transition, Path=DisplayA}" />
                <ContentControl Name="b" Visibility="Hidden" Content="{Binding ElementName=transition, Path=DisplayB}" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=transition, Path=State}" Value="A">
                <Setter TargetName="a" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="a" Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideStoryboard}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=transition, Path=State}" Value="B">
                <Setter TargetName="b" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <Setter TargetName="b" Property="RenderTransform">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding ElementName=container, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideStoryboard}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Which is applied as follows**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="_exampleView" Content="{Binding SelectedExample.View}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SwipeTransition}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

first a big thanks for the link.

May be you should look at this post [How to create a WPF-like data trigger in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578970/how-to-create-a-wpf-like-data-trigger-in-silverlight) they stated that VSM is the way to go for silverlight.

Comment: Hey there, and thanks :) Yes I'm not too experienced with VSM, or Silverlight for that matter. I've integrated the above with a WPF app but I'm also writing a cross-platform equivalent in SL4. I guess the whole VSM equivalent for the storyboard would be useful too. Can you shed any light or hints on how I could implement this? Going to look up VSM and do some studying, but any info at all would be gratefully received!